# onKeyPress couldn't be triggered with "button" in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am building a drum machine and one of the challenges is to set up keyboard events to the pads displayed.
Please take a look at the [code](https://codepen.io/john-huang/pen/xxqrjZy) I wrote. There is no event triggered when I smashed the button on my keyboard. Is there anything wrong here? I did a little bit research and I found out that in most cases onKeyPress is bound to `<div>`. Is it true that onKeyPress can only be used along with `<div>`?

```
    const keys={
  "Q-pad":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/SD0025.mp3",
  "W-pad":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/SD0010.mp3",
  "E-pad":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/SD0000.mp3",
  "A-pad":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/RS.mp3",
  "S-pad":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/OH25.mp3",
  "D-pad":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/MA.mp3",
  "Z-pad":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/CY0010.mp3",
  "X-pad":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/CH.mp3",
  "C-pad":"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/CB.mp3"
}
const keyboards=["Q","W","E","A","S","D","Z","X","C"]
const audioQ= new Audio()
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
    }
    this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this)
    this.handleKeyPress=this.handleKeyPress(this)
  }
  handleKeyPress(event){
    console.log(event.key)
  }
handleClick(event){
  const {name}=event.target
  const playSound = new Audio(keys[name])
  playSound.play() 
}
  render(){
   const keyboardsComponent= keyboards.map((key,index)=>(
     <input type="button" className="drum-pad" id={key+'-pad'+index} value={key} name={key+'-pad'} onClick={this.handleClick} onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}/>
    ))
   console.log(keyboardsComponent)
    return(
      <div>
        <h1 className="title">Drum machine</h1>
        <div id="drum-machine" className="container"> 
         {keyboardsComponent}
        </div>
      </div> 
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to rethink here where the `keypress` event should be attached. **Key events** demand focus and in your case, I think `document` itself would be a good place to attach the event listener. I have modified your codepen to do the same (used `keydown` instead of `keypress` since [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) states it being deprecated).

Another small typo was you didn't `bind` your `handleKeyPress` and directly called it.

The new React code :-

```
const keys = {
  "Q-pad": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/SD0025.mp3",
  "W-pad": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/SD0010.mp3",
  "E-pad": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/SD0000.mp3",
  "A-pad": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/RS.mp3",
  "S-pad": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/OH25.mp3",
  "D-pad": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/MA.mp3",
  "Z-pad": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/CY0010.mp3",
  "X-pad": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/CH.mp3",
  "C-pad": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/CB.mp3"
};
const keyboards = ["Q", "W", "E", "A", "S", "D", "Z", "X", "C"];
const audioQ = new Audio();
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
  }
  handleKeyPress(event) {
    const key = `${event.key.toUpperCase()}-pad`;
    this.handleAudioPlay(key);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyPress);
  }

  handleAudioPlay(name) {
    const playSound = new Audio(keys[name]);
    playSound?.play();
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    const { name: key } = event.target;
    this.handleAudioPlay(key);
  }
  render() {
    const keyboardsComponent = keyboards.map((key, index) => (
      <input
        type="button"
        className="drum-pad"
        id={key + "-pad" + index}
        value={key}
        name={key + "-pad"}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      />
    ));
    return (
      <div className="container-box">
        <h1 className="title">Drum machine</h1>
        <div id="drum-machine" className="container">
          {keyboardsComponent}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/lapstjup/pen/BaWZvgd)

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are running into here is related to how HTML and Javascript allows and handles input from the user. This is because a button input is not always in a 'focused' state [read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus), and hence, Javascript is not receiving input events from the element as the button is not strictly receiving any.

The way to resolve this issue is realistically through CSS. The method most commonly used is using a standard text input field as shown below which is autofocused and maybe as a listener to always re-focus the element incase the user clicks outside of it.

```
<input type="text" autoFocus onKeyPress={() => {...}}/>
```

You would likely use CSS to hide the element so that the user is not aware of its existence as it acts only as interference and brings no real user insight by its inclusion.

The key press event function would likely contain code similar to the code below, in which the event is labled as the variable **e**, the key pressed is parsed through and convereted to uppercase so if the user types 'q', the 'Q'
pad is still activated.

```
const sound = new Audio(keys[`${e.key.toUpperCase()}-pad`]);
sound.play()
```

Now, your code should work just fine, keeping in mind that the input field cannot be made hidden, as it must be displayed as a valid memeber of the DOM to recieve and transmit events and only made invisible using the [opacity parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) in CSS.